# Azimuthal Orthographic projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, azimuth

I'm trying to create a globe view in QGIS 3.16.1 with an Azimuthal Orthographic projection. This is my projection codes:

```
+proj=ortho +lat_0=32.4279 +lon_0=53.688 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371000 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
```

After the new projection are defined and there was no error, after applying this new projection, my map does not appear spherical (globe veiw). What is the problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I've done this.

First start QGIS and load Natural Earth coastline data. The coordinates in this data are lat-long EPSG:4326. It looks like this:

[image]

because the coordinate system for the project is:

[image]

set in the bottom right control.

Now I do "Settings, Custom Projections" and add yours:

[image]

And I click the "Validate" button and its all good. Back to the map and nothing has changed.

Click on the "EPSG:4326" button at bottom right and find that new coordinate system in the "Predefined Coordinate Reference System" list:

[image]

you can see it as "SO Question" and it has a code of "USER:100043" - your code will be different. Select that, select "Apply" and return to the map and:

[image]

an earth sphere view. (Note I've done coastlines here not polygons). The project coordinate reference bottom right now shows:

[image]

that I am using that custom projection. I can switch this back to epsg:4326 if I want to get back to that projection in my map.